# Fire a workflow annually / yearly for every item on the date it was created

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, custom-list

In my employee list I have a `Joining Date` and `Email` field. I have to send a congratulation mail to the employee every year. Is it possible with workflow?

How can I do this?

Comment: what version of SharePoint you are using ?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do with a yearly timer job.
Configuring a queued workflow over a period will be complex and may cause a performance hit..As far I see, this is not possible from a workflow.

Comment: Can u please describe what to do with the timer job? the email will sent the specific date it was created

Comment: You can schedule the timer job to run yearly/ monthly/hourly/after 15 mins etc. Now yours can be a daily timer job which will check the users date of joining with today's date and if it is exact one year you can configure an email to the concerned user. If you are unaware of time job please go through basic msdn articles and it will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Information Management Policy Settings" of SharePoint.

1. Go to your list on which you want to fire workflow
2. List settings -> Permissions and Management, click on Information Management Policy Settings link.
3. Click on item content-type, in Edit Policy policy page please click on Enable Retention
4. Once you click on enable retention page will be refreshed and  you will see link "Add a retention stage..." link
5. Create Event According to your need (created date + no of days) and in action select start workflow which you want to start

Comment: Then what you are going to do the next coming years? Every year are you going to change the retention policy. read the question carefully.

Comment: No please create recursive action

Comment: Please try this from your end and you will know what you are doing wrong.